# kubectl get hpa targets:unknow

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have installed kubeadm. Heapster show me metrics, but hpa no

**kubectl get hpa**

```
NAME      REFERENCE          TARGETS          MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE

httpd     Deployment/httpd   <unknown> / 2%   2         5         2          19m
```

**kubeadm version**

```
kubeadm version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.6", GitCommit:"7fa1c1756d8bc963f1a389f4a6937dc71f08ada2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-16T18:21:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**docker version**

Client:

```
Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 22:00:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Can you add your deployment?

Comment: In my case, the "resources" and "requests" were in the same indentation but the "request" should come under the "resource" as sub category

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution:

```
kubectl describe hpa
```

> failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu on container httpd in pod default/httpd-796666570-2h1c6

Change the yaml of deployment and add:

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu:400m
```

Then `kubectl describe hpa`

> failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from heapster

Wait a few minutes and all works fine.

Answer (score 14):

You may have had to enable a metrics-server. Heapster is now deprecated. Also make sure you have Kubernetes version greater than 1.7. You can check this buy typing `kubectl get nodes`.

You can enable the metrics server by looking at the minikube addons.

`minikube addons list` gives you the list of addons.

`minikube addons enable metrics-server` enables metrics-server.

Wait a few minutes, then if you type `kubectl get hpa` the percentage for the `TARGETS <unknown>` should appear.

Answer (score 0):

In kubernetes it can say unknown for hpa. In this situation you should check several places.

1. In K8s 1.9 uses custom metrics. so In order to work your k8s cluster

with heapster you should check kube-controller-manager.
Add these parameters.

- --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients=false
- --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period=10s

based on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57673

2. Case you should change your heapster deployment.

   - --source=kubernetes:https://kubernetes.default?kubeletPort=10250&kubeletHttps=true&insecure=true parameter is enough.

I found this link very informative https://blog.inkubate.io/deploy-kubernetes-1-9-from-scratch-on-vmware-vsphere/

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable the metrics server which you can do it using the helm chart

helm chart is easy way to add the metrics server

```
helm install stable/metrics-server
```

wait for 3-4 minutes after pods started running and you open `kubectl get hpa` you can check there target is showing values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your spec has this part properly configured:

```
 metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: {{ .Values.autoscaling.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage}}
```

In my case I had `name: Memory` with uppercase `M` and that cost me a day to find out.